# "brew install python" without Xcode in Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, homebrew, python

I've been able to get brew to install many packages on Snow Leopard using just the `gcc` library without installing all of Xcode.

I had installed Python as well as PosgreSQL from the gui installer and both were working fine, but was getting the following error after installing `psycopg`

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/mikekilmer/Envs/GLITCH/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/postgresql/lib/libpq.5.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/mikekilmer/Envs/GLITCH/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
Reason: image not found
```

Tried installing PosgreSQL with brew and got same error so decided to try reinstalling python with brew and am getting following error:

```
error: SecurityHI/SecurityHI.h: No such file or directory
```

It appears that `SecurityHI/SecurityHI.h` is part of Xcode, the (4 gig) compatible version of which I am downloading now.

But am curious if anyone else has had luck getting Python, PosgreSQL, psycopg working on a mac without X Tools. Am open to the idea that I'm being stubborn trying to avoid X Tools, and also wondering if it's high time to upgrade to a new computer.

This one:

```
Model Name: MacBook Pro
Model Identifier:   MacBookPro5,4
Processor Name: Intel Core 2 Duo
Processor Speed:     2.53 GHz
Number Of Processors:   1
Total Number Of Cores:  2
L2 Cache:   3 MB
Memory: 4 GB
```

I had already upgraded to Lion which ground the speed to a crawl, so went through the grueling process of downgrading from Lion back to Snow Leopard.

Comment: Home-brew requires a Xcode command line C compiler (note not just library) Also what are X tools?

Comment: What process did you follow to downgrade? this might be solved easily by installing 10.6.8 cleanly with no data migration to an external drive and then installing homebrew + python and then migrating data.

Comment: You mean downgrading from Lion to Snow Leopard? I don't think I documented it. Probably something along these lines: https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-3351. What I think I finally ended up doing was a clean install of Mavericks, installed all of XCode and used Homebrew to install postgres and python which are now in `/usr/local/bin`.